# Error in Sys.setenv(PATH = new_path) : wrong length for argument

Tags: reticulate

after i setenv path, i can't  use_condaenv("r-reticulate"); and py_avialable is False
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot2f3.png)